# best way to plot web based graph in Python

Tags: python, numpy, plotly

Is there a python package to generate web based interactive bar graphs?

I have the following requirements:

- I cannot use plotly, matplotlib as they depend on numpy (lots of dependencies). My environment cannot install any such packages, however I can try using the source of the package.
- I need cross-platform package

Comment: is it possible to add numpy in your env?

Comment: "web based interactive bar graphs" - what do you mean by this? Do you want to have some graph that people can click on "drill down" that is fed by data you generate in Python? Python doesn't run on the browser, so there is no interactivity that can be provided by Python. At most, it can generate static graphs of data at a point in time - to animate or interact with them, you need a client side library. So, I ask again - what exactly do you need?

Comment: `At most, it can generate static graphs of data at a point in time - to animate or interact with them, you need a client side library.` Its true that python is not client side , but there are libaries that does client side thing for you : bokeh.pydata.org is most complete html5 , d3.js base plotting solution for python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rely on d3.js if you want to do without any packages.
Generate data from python , render in d3.js for plotting , and interactivity.
Not reusable much , not suitalbe if project is huge.
http://d3js.org

If you are looking for full stack (which will generate plots for you and you can host on web server) look at docs.bokeh.org . It depends on :

```
Jinja2
numpy 
packaging 
pillow
python-dateutil 
PyYAML 
six 
tornado
```

They are automatically installed by using contiuum.io Anaconda/MiniConda Python distribution.

Using conda package manger you do not need to worried about installing binary packages  , Anaconda python distribution offers everything you need in your scenario. It have `conda` package manager , which install platform independent `Binaries` with all the dependancies. Thats mean you do not need Extra package manager or Compiler (GCC) to building binary from scratch at all.

I have tested conda on Bare-bone linuxes without packages and it works perfectly.
http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html
to do it :

Download miniconda:

```
wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-3.5.5-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

install it (no root needed):

bash Miniconda-3.5.5-Linux-x86_64.sh

then do:

```
conda create -n plotting_env python
conda update conda
conda install bokeh
```

Conda is Full (dependancy resolving) , cross platform , packagemanager which already have Virtualenv-style support.
It will install binary of all need libaries (including C libaries) without needing OS provided package manager.
Then code away!

Comment: Thanks, but isn't there any package that I could use? Most of the packages seem to depend on numpy

Comment: Numpy is very important piece of software for python to generate / mainipulate / parse arrays in fastest and memory efficient way (very close to performance of C). If possible you should go with continuum.io distribution of python: Miniconda , and install numpy (it is totally cross platform).

Comment: Thanks, I have experience with virtualenv; conda looks similar to it. 
Anyways, here is my concern: The python package I write will run from NXOS (Cisco Nexus OS, which has Linux Kernel, doesn't have a way to install packages). Is there a way to package the numpy/matplotlib into binary using conda and just use it? Does that make sense

Comment: That is what i am talking about. Continuum Anaconda provides you everythint. It is not just a virtual env , it is full stack python , with C Base libaries already included. , i will update my answer with more details.

Comment: Answer edited, check.

Comment: Yes, I accept the answer

Comment: cook , Did my soultion worked for you?

Comment: Hi, yes... I am definitely going to use Conda. Thanks for that!! But instead of bokeh, I am planning to use some that gives more interactivity (e.i interactive co-ordinates of a graph) using nvd3 http://python-nvd3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html 

I am planning to use Conda to build my package into binary on a Linux Server and then directly use the binary library on my Nexus Device (where I cannot install Conda/other packages)